# Best way to update a CakePHP installation with Git

Tags: git, cakephp

I would like to use Git to update my CakePHP installation without changing my current configuration.

I use :

```
git clone -b 2.x git://github.com/cakephp/cakephp.git
```

But that only makes a folder "cakephp" with Cake.

What is the right approach ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, the command is `git pull` to "update" a clone of a repository. If you want to manage your projects CakePHP dependency, then you should use composer. https://getcomposer.org/

It seems like you have no idea how git or composer works, explaining all of this would be just to much, that's why documentation exists: Read the documentation of both tools, [git](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial) and [composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) and how to set up your project with composer, [it's in the official docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/advanced-installation.html#installing-cakephp-with-composer) of CakePHP. This makes it pretty simple to update CakePHP in your project by simply calling `composer update`.

Technically you can clone and pull all your dependencies and commit them into your project but this just doesn't make much sense. There is no absolute "right approach", but using composer is today the most convenient and reliable way to manage your projects dependencies. I think it can be said that this is considered best practice.